# Iterartor - How to traverse for specific records

Tags: java, iterator

I have executed a query using JDBC and traversing the resultset I have stored all fields in List in java.

```
List<String> dataList=new ArrayList<String>();
        while(res.next())
        {
            dataList.add(res.getString(1));
            dataList.add(res.getString(2));
            dataList.add(res.getString(3));
            dataList.add(res.getString(4));
            dataList.add(res.getString(5));
            dataList.add(res.getString(6));
            dataList.add(res.getString(7));
        }
        Iterator<String> it= dataList.iterator();
```

As I have added directly into list so how can I get this 7 fields while traversing the iterator.
Means:

```
while(it.hasNext())
{
   String f1=it.next();

}
```

Like wise everytime I want 7 fields at a time
and next 7, next 7.......  so on
Using this while loop how can I get those 7 fields (one row in table having 7 field) at a time.

I get little bit confuse here. Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is actually create another object that stores all seven of the values.

Then create a list of these entries so that you can access one row at a time, which is what I think you are asking.

First create a class for the row.

```
private static class Entry {
    String[] row;

    public Entry ( ResultSet r ) {
        row = new String [ 7 ];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
            row[i] = r.getString(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Using that, you can then create a list of Entry objects.

```
List<Entry> entryList = new ArrayList <Entry> ();

while(res.next())
{
    entryList.add ( new Entry ( res ) );
}
```

Then, you can go ahead and loop through entryList and get any specific entry you would want.

Of course, if you have specific values, it might be wise to create instance variables of type String for Entry rather than an array of Strings.

By that I mean you could do this:

```
private static class Entry {
    String column1; // rather than name column1 use what the column semantically represents

    String column2;

    // ...

    public Entry ( ResultSet r ) {
        column1 = r.getString(1);
        // ...
    }
```

This way, you can also calls like `r.getInt(i)` for certain columns which have an different type other than String.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think your List declaration should be

```
List<Any DAO Object> instead of List<String>
```

While fetching from resultset, create a DAO object, add all fetched data into that object and then add that object into the list.

Then you can iterate and get each DAO object at each iteration.

Comment: That makes sense! I didn't realize you and I actually said the same thing. Maybe I shouldn't have posted...

Comment: @Kaushik sometimes it happens. You got the problem, thats enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DatabaseMetaData class,

```
private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

  private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb";

  private static final String USERNAME = "root";

  private static final String PASSWORD = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

    DatabaseMetaData metadata = connection.getMetaData();
    ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getColumns(null, null, "users", null);
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      String name = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
      String type = resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME");
      int size = resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");

      System.out.println("Column name: [" + name + "]; type: [" + type + "]; size: [" + size + "]");
    }
    connection.close();
  }
```